# How to place facet blocks

Tags: blocks, search, 9

I got Search API and Facets configured, built a View Source, and connected the Facet to that source. Now I'm stuck with how to present that widget!

With D7 Facets, it configured Blocks that I could place. That isn't the case with D9. Anyone have a helpful hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special really. You need to set up each facet individually so that it will become available as a block. Go to `admin/config/search/facets` and click on "Add facet".

[image]

The available facet can then be found in the block managements "Place block" dialog by searching for the name of the facet.

[image]